# New apps not showing in file manager when adding to application launch bar

Tags: lubuntu, launcher

This is about Lubuntu 15.04 vivid which is a system upgrade from 14.10

I have a problem adding news apps to the application launch bar because the new apps don't show.

I installed apps like VLC player, Skype, Chromium etc. I want to add these apps to the application launch bar. Going to add/remove panel items, then click application launch bar and preferences. The small file manager window shows up with left the launchers and right the installed applications. So far all good. However, *none of newly installed apps is showing on the right*.
So I can not add them to the application launch bar. The new apps do show in the normal menu and they work fine but that doesn't matter or help for this issue.

As I just discovered, the same happens if I want to set a default application for opening a file, e.g. VLC to open a MP4 video file.

Comment: Look into `/usr/share/applications` directory. For all (or most ) of the installed apps, you have `.desktop` files. If you can find a `.desktop` files for those apps, you can then create a link, place it on desktop, and then pin it to launch bar. If you don't find it, try using `which skype` and `which chromium-browser` in terminal. That should let you know where the binary files are located, in fact, I'm 99% certain it will say `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't pin links from the desktop to the launch bar.

The .desktop files are in /usr/share/applications but is this where Panel Preferences is looking? If it is why doesn't it see the recent files? If it is not, then where is it looking?

Comment: OK, so what did you find ? did you find `.desktop` files for your specific applications ? Did you find the executable ( binary ) files ?

Comment: Well I have already confirmed the .desktop files and I can also confirm the /usr/bin location but this does not make me pin the apps to the application launch bar.

Comment: How about copying the files to desktop and then trying to pin the apps ? By default they're should be owned by root. A copy is owned by your username, so that should work

Comment: As I replied before, I can copy the .desktop files to the desktop, but from there I can find no option to pin them to the launch bar.

Comment: Another user in the chat suggested this :"all apps that come with a .desktop file can be added to the panel via "Application Launchbar Settings..." in case the Lauchbar panel application was added.
  
Just right click on the App Launcher and open the "Settings" menu item." Let me know if this helps

Comment: I am also running into this issue: some applications are visible in the normal "start" menu, but not in the Application Launch Bar selector, nor in the "open with..." context menu. What causes this to happen? I cannot find any difference between the .desktop files in /usr/share/applications of apps which are visible, and apps which are not.

Comment: Suddenly, after running desktop-file-install (even if on an existing .desktop file), the apps which didn't show up, now show up. (found about this on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866234)

Comment: After repeated tries I had success with running desktop-file-install. The command actually returned permission errors, but afterwards I found the missing files in the Application Launch Bar selector. I do not really understand what I have done but I was close to installing another Lubuntu version and this was my last attempt. Thanks very much mauritslamers for bringing up the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/app.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

And then check Application Launcher Bar again and it will appear.
It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into same problem, and what fixed it for me was making .desktop file avaliable to all users, that is:

```
chmod 777 /user/share/applications/<theapp>.desktop
```

After doing that it appeared among the apps you can choose in the "Application Launch Bar" settings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **"Application Launch Bar"** starts to see some ***.desktop** files after any change to their permissions. 
So, you can change permissions for **/usr/share/applications/<app>.desktop** and then change it back again. You can, for example, set the execution bit, save the changes and the drop that bit back.
I did it in **Midnight Commander** run under superuser:

```
sudo mc
```

and then going to **File, Advanced chown**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Stanislav and Uto_dev are in the good way. The problem is date of file.

This was my solution:

```
touch /usr/share/applications/<app>.desktop
```

This changes modification time of file to 'now'. After this I can see application and add it to panel.